# Blowfish encryption Android

Tags: android, string, encryption, arrays

I want to encrypt a String with Blowfish in my Android App. The result should be a string because I will send it to my server.
I have following code:

```
KeyGenerator keygenerator;
try {
    keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
    SecretKey secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();

    String Key = settings.getString("key", "");
    byte[] KeyData = Key.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec KS = new SecretKeySpec(KeyData, "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KS);

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
    message = new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println("encrypt ok");
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("encrypt error");
}
```

The Problem is, that the variable message contains something like

> R??C?    j

But when I decrypt this with Javascript (the JS works fine...) there is returned an empty string... (I couldn't see anything on my website)

I think that the problem is near

```
message = new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");
```

But how can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever use `String` as a holder for byte array.

Either pass byte arrays directly, or use the proper text representation of binary data, such as Base64 or HEX.

In your example, you need to replace `String message = new String(encrypted, "UTF-8");` and similar code with something like `String message = Base64.encode(encrypted);` (the exact call method details should be corrected for the chosen Base64 implementation). There are a lot of Base64 implementations, [Android even has one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) out of the box.

Comment: But in the JavaScript part of my project I have to decrypt a String and not a Base64 string...

Comment: When I try `Base64.encode(encrypted);` I get the following error: The method encode(byte[], int) in the type Base64 is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])